# Find duplicates in an ArrayList and set the duplicates to new ArrayList dynamically using Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to find duplicate values in an ArrayList and set the duplicates to new ArrayList dynamically.See my list

```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add("A");
   list.add("B");
   list.add("A");
   list.add("B");
   list.add("C");
   list.add("D");
```

According to this list, I would like to get four ArrayList like this

```
  List 1 that contains {A,A} 
  List 2 that contains {B,B}
  List 3 that contains {C}
  List 4 that contains {D}
```

ArrayList may be occur dynamically.so please share me some ideas or links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use a `Map`. Check is the map contains a key of the String. If it doesn't create a new List and add it to the map. If it does, then just add the String the list already in the map.

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> getMap(List<String> list) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String s: list) {
        if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
            List<String> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
            mapList.add(s);
            map.put(s, mapList);
        } else {
            ((List<String>)map.get(s)).add(s);
        }
    } 
    return map;
}
```

Here's running example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestLIst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("D");

        Map<String, List<String>> map = getMap(list);
        printMapAsLists(map);
    }

    public static Map<String, List<String>> getMap(List<String> list) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (String s: list) {
            if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
                List<String> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
                mapList.add(s);
                map.put(s, mapList);
            } else {
                ((List<String>)map.get(s)).add(s);
            }
        } 
        return map;
    }

    public static void printMapAsLists(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        for (List<String> list : map.values()) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
[D]
[A, A]
[B, B]
[C]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following solution. See comments for more information about what it is doing.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");
    Collections.sort(list); // Sort 'list'

    List<ArrayList<String>> arrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); // Store final results
    int k = 0; // To keep index of the arrays in 'arrays'

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size();) { // No increment since it is incremented by 'i += count' inside the body
        int count = Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i)); // Get number of occurrences of an element
        arrays.add(new ArrayList<String>()); // When its a new String, add a new ArrayList
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            arrays.get(k).add(list.get(i)); // Add 'number of occurrences' times the String
        }
        i += count; // Increment to skip elements that were already added (repeated elements)
        k++;
    }

     // Just to print the final array
    for (ArrayList<String> arr : arrays) {
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A A 
B B 
C 
D
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this.

```
    HashMap<String,List<String>> result = new HashMap<>(); 
    for(String s:list) {
        List<String> l = result.get(s);
        if(l == null) {
            l = new ArrayList<String>();
            result.put(s,l);
        }
        l.add(s);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

output

```
{D=[D], A=[A, A], B=[B, B], C=[C]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set to detect dups:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// populate list
List<String> dups = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (Iterator<String> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    String s = i.next();
    if (set.add(s)) // returns true if not a dup
        i.remove();
    else
        dups.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution using set -

```
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

Set<String> uniqueStrings = new TreeSet<>();
for (String s : list) {
  uniqueStrings.add(s);
}

for (String str : uniqueStrings) {
  List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String s : list) {
    if (s.equals(str)) {
      l.add(s);
    }
  }
  lists.add(l);
}
```